# Parsing arrays in Json using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

Parsing arrays in json using Gson.
I have this following json and trying to parse it.

```
{
"success": true,
"message": "success message",
"data": [
    {
        "city": "cityname",
        "state": "statename",
        "pin": 0,
         "name" :{
                   "firstname" : "user"
                 },
         "id" :"emailid"
    }],
"status" : "done"
}
```

So, I have created pojo classes using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Now, I want to parse the array, for value "city".This is how I did but not sure what is wrong here.

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 Records obj = gson.fromJson(response,Records.class);
 try {

     JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(obj.getData());

     for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
     {
          JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
          String city = object.getString("city");
          AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
          dialog.setMessage(city);
          dialog.show();

      }}

    catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And this is what getData() is defined in model class:

```
public class Records {

//////
private ArrayList<Datum> data = null;
public ArrayList<Datum> getData() {
    return data;
}
```

Comment: but city is not an array...is just a string.... I dont get your qestion

Answer (score 0):

this is not required:

```
try {

 JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(obj.getData());
 ...
}
   catch
...
```

you just need to do

```
Records obj = gson.fromJson(response,Records.class);
```

and then

```
obj.getData();
```

would be great if you check that getData() is not null, beacuse something xould go wrong when deserialising

---

for getting the city: use the getter in the Datum class, you have at the end a list of those obejcts when you call getData

```
public String getCity() {
return city;
}
```

Comment: ok I get this whole point. But I want to parse the value for only "city". So I used an array for that as "data" is having array entries.

Comment: then do a loop and do ask the city

Comment: yeah that was the whole idea..i did the same thing as mentioned in question, but not knowing whats wrong